# OR query in rethink

Tags: arrays, rethinkdb

Is it possible to do OR search on values of array in Rethink.

Eg: I have table called "post" with field "tags" which is an array. I want to do an OR search on values of tags.

```
post1 {
tags : ["young","agreesive"]
}

post2 {
tags : ["cricket","India"]
}
```

Give me all posts which contains tags "young" or "cricket" should return be both the posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mlucy said, you can use `filter` in conjunction with `or` and `contains` to get all documents with a specific tag.

If you have an array of tags, you can do the following too:

```
var tags = ["young", "cricket"];

r.table('posts').filter(function (row) {
  return r.expr(tags).contains(function (value) { 
    return row("tags").contains(value) 
  });
})
```

This is more easily extensible than using `or`.

### Multi Index

You can also create a [multi-index](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/#multi-indexes) for that property. Multi-indexes let you lookup data by any of the values in an array. So, for example:

```
r.table("posts").indexCreate("tags", {multi: true})
r.table("posts").getAll("young", "cricket", {index: "tags"})
```

This query would get all the documents with the "young" and "cricket" tag, and it's more performant and cleaner than using the nested `contains`.

Comment: Thanks Jorge :) For array of tags, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `or` and `contains`:

```
r.table('posts').filter(function(row) {
  return row('tags').contains('young').or(row('tags').contains('cricket'));
})
```